# Python Klein - How to return Excel file as attachment?

Tags: python, excel, klein-mvc

i'm use [Python Klein](https://klein.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for my small API. Can return csv as response, but is this possible to return Excel file?  Flask has this functional but what about Klein?

**Task:**

Have Excel file on hard drive and want return it to as attachment, so user can download it via API call.

**Example:**
With csv file all is working good like

```
   @app.route('/download/',  branch=True, methods=['GET'])
   def download(request):
       request.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
       request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/csv')
       request.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=test.csv')
       file = open('test.csv', "r")
       csv_data = file.read() 
       return csv_data
```

*But how to be with an Excel file?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found solution:**

```
from twisted.web.static import File
from klein import Klein
app = Klein()
@app.route('/', branch=True)
def pg_index(request):
    request.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
    request.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=test.xlsx'.format(list_id))
    return File('./test.xlsx')
```